# Move a specific <td> element with CSS grid?

Tags: css, vue.js, grid, css-grid

I'm building a dynamic table combined with CSS grid and I wish to move out the left-most `<th>` and `<td>` just a tad. Not really sure how to move a specific element that resides inside a div "inside" a `<table>`.

Basically, here's what I wish to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjekU.jpg

And here's a fiddle that shows what I'm working with: https://jsfiddle.net/anr1exp2/

Basically, the left-most `<td>` holds all my project names and I just wanna scoot that over a bit because it sits too tight with the rest of the data. Not sure how to do this as I'm combining a table with CSS grid.

PS: I have tried creating the entire table with CSS grid only but since my table is heavily dynamic, it was super hard to make that happen and just a huge pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style

```
th:first-child, td:first-child {
  min-width: 120px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Adjust the min-width value to whatever you want

Also note that in reality you are no using grid for your table, it's just inside one of the grid cells

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcs7gz69/)

To do this without changing the layout, use a transform:

```
th:first-child, td:first-child {
  transform: translateX(-18px);
}
```

[second fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uLd3f7h1/)

Comment: Thanks a ton! Just what I needed.

Comment: Hey man, I just realized that this doesn't fully solve the issue since it moves everything else to the side as well, is it possible to move the `<td>` part without affecting the container? I wanna keep the table size exactly the same, just move the actual `td` a bit..

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I have edited the answer, please check